# How to dynamically create nested Divs with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a translated input field for each language configured in my application parameters. Thus I generate Divs, Labels and Fields dynamically, in order to get something like this (inside a table cell):

```
<td>
  <div class="translation-block">
    <div class="row mat-form-row translated-name-row">
      <div class="mat-form-field col-md-12">
        <label for="definition-name-en" class="mat-form-field-label"> name </label>
        <label for="definition-name-en" class="translation-label"> en </label>
        <input id="definition-name-en" name="annotations[0][name][en]" type="text" value="Standard code, follows Eurostat Standard Code List Guidelines" class="mat-input-element translated_name_input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mat-form-row translated-name-row">
      <div class="mat-form-field col-md-12">
        <label for="definition-name-de" class="translation-label"> de </label>
        <input id="definition-name-de" name="annotations[0][name][de]" type="text" value="" class="mat-input-element translated_name_input">
      </div>
    </div>
etc.
  </div>
</td>
```

The issue is that Divs are not nested the way I instantiate them. The generated code is:

```
<td>
  <div class="translation-block">
    <div class="row mat-form-row translated-name-row"></div>
      <div class="mat-form-field col-md-12"></div>
etc.
```

I use JQuery, and ave been searching and testing several solutions around without actually solving the issue. How can I properly nest the Divs?

Here is my script:

```
  function createCellTranslatedInput(id, columnName, value) {
    var languages = <%= raw parameters_for('languages').sort_by { |e| [e.property == current_language.to_s ? 0 : 1, e.property] }.map {|l| l.property} %>;
    console.log("Languages: ", languages);
    var td = $('<td/>');
    var divOpen = $('<div class="translation-block">');
    var divClose = $('</div>');
    var section = $('<div class="translation-block">');
    for (var language in languages) {
      console.log("Language: ", languages[language]);
      var name = ('annotations').concat('[', (rowCount).toString(), '][', columnName,'][', languages[language],']');
      var id = 'definition-' + columnName + '-' + languages[language] ;
      var field = $(    
        '<input>', {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            type: 'text',
            value: value[languages[language]],
            class: "mat-input-element translated_name_input"
          });
      section.append('<div class="row mat-form-row translated-' + columnName + '-row">')
        .append('<div class="mat-form-field col-md-12">')
        .append( (language > 0) ? null : '<label for="definition-' + columnName + '-' + languages[language] +'" class="mat-form-field-label"> ' + columnName + ' </label>')
        .append('<label for="definition-' + columnName + '-' + languages[language] +'" class="translation-label"> ' + languages[language] + ' </label>')
        .append(field);
      console.log("Section:", section);
    }
    section.appendTo(td);
    return td;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using append wrong.  You need to create a div and append to the div. You instead are appending a start div, hoping it will work. This whole thing can be rewritten to be much more elegant using templating/template literals for example

```js
const createCellTranslatedInput = (id, columnName, value) => {
  // Assuming `languages` is an array of language codes like ['en', 'de']
  let languages = <%= raw parameters_for('languages').sort_by { |e| [e.property == current_language.to_s ? 0 : 1, e.property] }.map {|l| l.property} %>;

  console.log("Languages: ", languages);

  let $td = $('<td/>'); // Creates a closed TD element
  let $section = $('<div class="translation-block"/>'); // Creates a closed div element

  // Generate all rows as a single HTML string
  let rowsHtml = languages.map((language, index) => {
    let inputId = `definition-${columnName}-${language}`;
    let nameAttribute = `annotations[0][${columnName}][${language}]`;
    let inputValue = value[language] || ''; // Assuming `value` is an object with language codes as keys

    return `<div class="row mat-form-row translated-${columnName}-row">
        <div class="mat-form-field col-md-12">
          ${index === 0 ? `<label for="${inputId}" class="mat-form-field-label"> ${columnName} </label>` : ''}
          <label for="${inputId}" class="translation-label"> ${language} </label>
          <input id="${inputId}" name="${nameAttribute}" type="text" value="${inputValue}" class="mat-input-element translated_name_input">
        </div>
      </div>`;
  }).join(''); // Join all row strings into a single string

  // Append the combined HTML string to the section
  $section.append(rowsHtml);

  $td.append($section);
  return $td;
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is clean and clear! Template strings are indeed much more efficient to describe these verbose Divs than trying to manipulate objects. It works perfectly, thanks!